# Mechanize with multiple pages

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize

```
search_1=raw_input('search criteria 1? ')
search_2=raw_input('search criteria 2? ')

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('website')
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['-c']=search_1
br['-c.rs']=search_2
br.set_handle_robots(False)
response=br.submit()
print response.read()
```

I run this mechanize script on one page, then the website will lead me to another page automatically wherein I need to run another mechanize script. My problem is that I don't know how to link them. How do you go about doing this nicely? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by link them ?

Comment: What I meant was when I fill in my appropriate forms and then I br.submit() I'll be taken to a new page with a new url. I wanted to be able to throw that next url into my next line of code to carry on with more form-filling. Does that make sense at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to submit and to stay on the same page with all forms filled.

Instead why not create second instance of the mechanize browser and work in both simultaneously? For example:

```
from mechanize import Browser

br0 = Browser()
br1 = Browser()

br0.open('http://www.example.com/')
br1.open('http://www.example.com/')
```

Or another option is to use back() after submition, but you still will have to refill the form. For example:

```
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()

r = br.open('http://www.example.com/')
r = br.open('http://www.google.com/')
r = br.back()

print r.read()
```

Comment: I think I'm being misunderstood, probably due to my communication skills. I mean to say that when I fill out the forms and hit submit I want mechanize to start working on the page that follows after the submission.

Comment: You already have code for that. After you submit the form, `br` becomes the next page that is loaded. So just continue using the next page with `br` variable, as you used the one that is in your example. (if this answers your question, just accept the answer or close the question)

Comment: Thanks. I thought that's how it was supposed to be done, but I wanted to check with people that had more experience than myself first. Again, thank you.